# Onclick function changing to the same function for all changed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

What I'm trying to do is based on data gotten via AJAX I am changing certain elements on the page to be different. A simplified version is this:

Example:

HTML:

```
<ul id="friends">
    <li id="1-1" onclick="dont_alert()"> Andy </li>
    <li id="1-2" onclick="dont_alert()"> Paul </li>
    <li id="1-3" onclick="dont_alert()"> Saul </li>
    <li id="1-4" onclick="dont_alert()"> Rita </li>
    <li id="1-5" onclick="dont_alert()"> Greg </li>
</ul>

<input type="button" onclick='callback()' value="Go!" />
```

Relevant JS:
    function alert_this(value) {
        alert(value);
    }

```
function dont_alert() {
    alert('...');
}

function callback() {
    var data_received = [["1","1","Andy"], ["1","5","Greg"]];
    for (friend in data_received) {
        if (data_received[friend][0] == undefined) continue;

        var friend_id = '#'+ data_received[friend][0] +'-'+ data_received[friend][1];
        $(friend_id).attr('onclick', '');
        $(friend_id).css('background', 'red');
        $(friend_id).click(function () { 
            alert_this(data_received[friend][2]);
        });
    }    
}
```

The result of this is both elements alert 'Greg' instead of the appropriate value.

Any prod towards the answer will be very much appreciated! :D

Comment: you're missing a few `var`s :)

Comment: That's not the problem, just hastily coded this up to show the problem. Joao had the solution though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a ***closure***, otherwise, the `.click()` handler will always alert the  value of the *last* assigned `friend` in the loop, since all they have is a *reference* to this variable.

```
function callback() {
    var data_received = [["1","1","Andy"], ["1","5","Greg"]];
    for (var friend in data_received) {
        if (data_received[friend][0] == undefined) continue;

        var friend_id = '#'+ data_received[friend][0] +'-'+ data_received[friend][1];
        console.log(friend_id);
        $(friend_id).attr('onclick', '');
        $(friend_id).css('background', 'red');
        (function() {
            var savedValue = data_received[friend][2];
            $(friend_id).click(function(){
                alert(savedValue);
            });
        })();
    }    
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XPdJF/)**.

Comment: Local to what? That's not the problem here.

Comment: @Eric: You're right, I've since edited my answer to reflect the real issue.

Comment: Ha, you're too quick for me! I knew I was missing something!

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't be using inline event handlers in your HTML. Instead, attach them with jQuery.

Your problem is with closures - `friend` has function scope, within `callback`. The event handlers create a closure on the `friend` variable. When `callback` finished, `friend == 1`. The event handlers then use this value. A fix is to use `$.each` to iterate your arrays, which creates a closure on the value of the variable.

#### HTML

```
<ul id="friends">
    <li id="1-1"> Andy </li>
    <li id="1-2"> Paul </li>
    <li id="1-3"> Saul </li>
    <li id="1-4"> Rita </li>
    <li id="1-5"> Greg </li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="go" value="Go!" />
```

#### Js

```
$('#friends').on('click', 'li', function() {
    alert('...');
});

$('#go').on('click', function() {
    var data_received = [["1","1","Andy"], ["1","5","Greg"]];
    $.each(data_received, function(i, friend) {
        if (friend[0] === undefined) return;

        $('#'+ friend[0] +'-'+ friend[1])
            .css('background', 'red');
            .click(function() { 
                alert(friend[2]);
                return false;
            });
    });
});
```